# Are the keys of __dict__ guaranteed toalways be string values (implementing custom __deepcopy__)

Tags: python

I am implementing `__deepcopy__()` method in base class of a data model hierarchy. Attributes of the original object are copied by calling `copy.deepcopy()` on the values of the original `__dict__` and assigning them to appropriate keys. Under conventional usage (i.e., nobody has gone and explicitly added complex objects to the original object's `__dict__` property directly), are these key values are always going to be strings and hence do not need to, in turn, be deep-copied as well?

For example, in the following code:

```
 def __deepcopy__(self, memo=None):
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    try:
        o = memo[id(self)]
    except KeyError:
        o = type(self).__new__(self.__class__)
        memo[id(self)] = o
    for k in self.__dict__:
        # o.__dict__[copy.deepcopy(k, memo)] = copy.deepcopy(self.__dict__[k], memo)
        o.__dict__[k] = copy.deepcopy(self.__dict__[k], memo)
    return o
```

The current line:

```
o.__dict__[k] = copy.deepcopy(self.__dict__[k], memo)
```

assumes that the keys in the `__dict__` symbol table are simple strings (or another type of object that does not require special handling).

Should I be using:

```
o.__dict__[copy.deepcopy(k, memo)] = copy.deepcopy(self.__dict__[k], memo)
```

instead, which allows for the keys in the symbol table to be themselves more complex or rich objects?

Comment: FWIW, `ipython`'s tab-complete throws a nice looking stack trace if you add a non-string key to an objects `__dict__` and then try to tab-complete an attribute name on that object. If `ipython` doesn't handle this case, it's probably not worth worrying about. I am surprised Python allows this, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes.  [The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) for classes says:

> A class has a namespace implemented by a dictionary object. Class attribute references are translated to lookups in this dictionary, e.g., `C.x` is translated to `C.__dict__["x"]`

which seems to make it clear that if you only use normal attribute assignment, you'll always get string keys.  (The section below on instances isn't as explicit but also refers to an "attribute dictionary" which is apparently meant to work the same as for classes.)

Of course, as you note in your question, people could do weird stuff, but if you assume nothing got added to the `__dict__` except by doing normal `obj.attr  = value` stuff, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

While it is certainly possible to add non-string keys to an object's `__dict__` (see below), there's no doubt the simpler version of your code would work.  I've never encountered anyone using non-string keys in object's `__dict__`.

If someone does something weird which violates this assumption and makes your code break, it's their fault. I'd claim your code is still correct and valid despite breaking in such weird cases.

Here's one way one can add non-string keys to an object's dict:

```
obj.__dict__.update({ object(): 666 })
obj.__dict__
=> {<object at 0x1002b1450>: 666}
```